# C# how to get referece to ContextMenuStrip from underlying sub menuitems of at least two levels

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip

How to get the referece to ContextMenuStrip from its underlying sub menuitem which is a ToolStripMenuItem of a ToolStripDropDownMenu which is a Dropdown of a ToolstripMenuItem of this ContextMenuStrip?

the problem lies in the ToolStripDropDownMenu class,where can't find a property refer to upperlevel objects such as its assciated ToolStripMenuItem.Its Parent,Container properties and GetContainerControl() method all return null.

My purpose is to know the SourceControl of the ContextMenuStrip when any of its underlying menu items are clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a backward loop to get the first [`OwnerItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.owneritem?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.OwnerItem)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) property of a given `ToolStripItem` (or one of the [derived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) classes) in a branch then you can get the main `ToolStrip` (which can be a  `ToolStrip`, `MenuStrip`, `StatusStrip`, or `ContextMenuStrip` control) through the [`ToolStripItem.Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.owner?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.Owner)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) property.

Consider the following extension methods:

```cs
public static class ToolStripExtensions
{
    public static ToolStrip GetMainToolStrip(this ToolStripItem tsi)
    {
        if (tsi == null) return null;
        if (tsi.OwnerItem == null) return tsi.Owner;

        var oi = tsi.OwnerItem;

        while (oi.OwnerItem != null) oi = oi.OwnerItem;

        return oi.Owner;
    }

    public static ToolStrip GetMainToolStrip(this ToolStrip ts)
    {
        ToolStrip res = ts;

        var m = ts as ToolStripDropDownMenu;

        if (m?.OwnerItem != null)
            res = GetMainToolStrip(m.OwnerItem);

        return res;
    }
}
```

Here's an example that shows how to get the [`ContextMenuStrip.SourceControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.sourcecontrol?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) in the [`ItemClicked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.itemclicked?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.ItemClicked)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) event:

```cs
private void cmnu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickedItem.GetMainToolStrip() is ContextMenuStrip cmnu)
        Console.WriteLine(cmnu.SourceControl.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OwnerItem` property to get the `ToolStripItem`:

```
private void toolStripComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = sender as ToolStripComboBox;
    var twoLevelParent = comboBox.OwnerItem.OwnerItem;
}
```

Comment: the case in ContextMenuStrip is different from other controls layed out on a form.

Comment: @Xiaoyuvax I tried with a real example. The abobe code works. I have a ContextMenuStrip with a Level1 item, which contains a Level2 item with a ToolStripComboBox with several items. When I select some item in the ComboBox and the code runs, in twoLevelParent I have Level1 ToolStripItem that you can cast to ToolStripMenuItem if you want.