# How to Control Which Object Used ToolStrip in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I have 100 buttons which created dynamically. Every button has same text and same name. Actually all of them is totally same. I added a property to my toolstrip menu called "color".

This is my function which must be change color.

```
private void colorfunc(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }
```

I created the toolstrip like this.

```
  ContextMenuStrip menu= new ContextMenuStrip();
  ToolStripMenuItem color= new ToolStripMenuItem("color");
   
  color.Click += colorfunc;
  menu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { color});
```

I want to do is when i right click to my button and after click the color item from toolstrip my button must be green. But i want to do is for only the button which is right clicked. Other 99 button must be stay like before.  How to i do that?

Comment: Is this in an event handler? If so maybe use the `sender` parameter. But without seeing any code it's hard to say.

Comment: [Get the SourceControl of a DropDownMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53263702/7444103)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21851539/17034

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72409829/14171304